# Google Sheets: Vlookup and IF condition

Tags: excel, function, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following sheet (sharing link with edit rights).

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zMnttx0AMCwjxo1vpqmU7OVNP13feaft990hnHoMSXk/edit?usp=sharing

I have created a workbook where data are pulled from Sheet 1 to Sheet 2 with Vlookup.

I m trying to create an if statement in vlookup where when the data is string for example "empty" then the respective cell to be actually empty.

Please have a look at my sheet I have created table it is very easy to understand.

Thank you!

Comment: have you tried something? What went wrong with what you tried?

Comment: Why link to the problem, especially when your link is volatile? How can that possibly be helpful to future visitors? If you cannot describe your specific issue, why should we waste time trying to decipher anything?

Comment: If time was important for you tehhowch you wouldn't waste it to answer my friend. I have no idea about formulas, tried several formulas I found but no luck Liora.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51788000/edit) your question and post what you have tried.

Comment: Comments are by definition not answers @nikos :) You should also clarify your tags - you've tagged both Excel and Google Sheets, while they are 100% not the same program.

Comment: you could nest it within an IF statement, but I'm unsure of your desired result. So is your first test is = empty, and your second is on the 2nd sheet, if your trying to test whether the data is one one sheet or the other you could nest your if statement with an if error.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a vlookup result to not show some result, you just need to test the formula result and, in case of "empty", return you an empty value as true, or repeat the formula if false. This is what I wrote in your sheet1 B3 cell, for instance:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP("MyData_C",Sheet1!$A$4:$B,2,FALSE)="empty","",VLOOKUP("MyData_C",Sheet1!$A$4:$B,2,FALSE))
```